# React JS To do list app | Get value and push to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a to do list application which is taking in two objects from a store set as default.

Having trouble taking what the user has inputted as their new "to do" item and pushing it to the store / application state.

If I click on the "Create new" button, this successfully creates a new to do item however, no text.

I am getting the value from the input with the handleChange function - I need to send that value as part of the createTodo function to the store.

The createToDo function is what calls the action to add a new "to do" item to the store. I can't figure out how to tie the input value to that function to create the new to do item.

Here is my code so far:

```
import React from "react";

import Todo from "../components/Todo";
import * as TodoActions from "../actions/TodoActions";
import TodoStore from "../stores/TodoStore";


export default class Featured extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      todos: TodoStore.getAll()
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    TodoStore.on("change", this.getTodos);
    console.log("count", TodoStore.listenerCount("change"));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    TodoStore.removeListener("change", this.getTodos);
  }

  getTodos() {
    this.setState({
      todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
    });
  }

  createTodo(text) {
    TodoActions.createTodo();
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let text = e.target.value;
    console.log(text);
  }

  reloadTodos() {
    TodoActions.reloadTodos();
  }


  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;

    console.log("todos", todos);

    const todoitems = todos.map((todoitem) => {
      return <Todo key={todoitem.id} {...todoitem} />
    });

    return (
      <div className="todolist-wrapper">
        <h1>To do list</h1>
        <button onClick={this.reloadTodos.bind(this)}>Reload</button>
        <ul>
          {todoitems}
        </ul>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <button onClick={this.createTodo.bind(this)}>Create new</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the value to your component's `state`:

```
constructor() {
  ...
  this.state = {
    todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
    value: ""
  }
}
```

You can add this as the `value` attribute of the `input` element itself (in order to let the initial `value` within your `state` control the initially-rendered value of the `input` element):

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

Then in your `handleChange` function, modify the state's value using `setState`:

```
handleChange(e) {
  let text = e.target.value;
  this.setState({
    value: text
  });
}
```

Now you can grab the `value` from your component's `state` within your `createTodo` function:

```
createTodo() {
  let text = this.state.value;
  TodoActions.createTodo(text);
}
```